# Fix problem with ajax and validate plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use validate plugin with rules and ajax, but page just reloading after click on submit button and validate plugin don't work.
Is there anybody who know how to fix it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form[name='test']").validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'action.php',
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
          var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
          alert(jsonData.result);
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form class='rd-mailform' method="post" id="myform" name="test">
  <div class="form-group"><label data-add-placeholder data-add-icon><input placeholder="Ваш Email" data-constraints="@Email" type="text" name="email"/></label></div>

  <div class="form-group btn-wr"><button class="btn-mailform" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="mfInfo"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I made a snippet and moved the validation to AFTER jQuery. The script works now. Please delete the question

Comment: Vote to close since the issue _is caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Hi, are you getting any error on console

Comment: No money, just no need to keep the question

Comment: Thank to all, I check again my code in clear page and it working.